# How do I get my variables from one function to another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

```
def getInt():
    while True:
        width = int(input("Enter width (1 - 60):"))
        if width > 1 and width < 60:
            break
        else:
            print("Please enter a valid input")
    while True:
        height = int(input("Enter width (1 - 20):"))
        if height > 1 and height < 20:
            break
        else:
            print("Please enter a valid input")
    return width, height


def calcPerimeter(width, height):
    perimeter = (2 * (width + height))
    return perimeter  

def calcArea(width, height):
    area = width * height
    return area


def main():
print('Results: {}'.format(getInt()))
print('The perimeter is {}' .format(calcPerimeter(width, height)))
print('The area is {}' .format(calcArea(width, height)))


main()
```

When I run, it says:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> main()
>
> print('The perimeter is {}' .format(calcPerimeter(width, height)))
>
> NameError: name 'width' is not defined

Comment: Do you know `variable scopes`? Do you think `width` is visible in `main` method?

Comment: `getInt()` returns width and height, but when you call `getInt()`, you aren't saving the returned values anywhere.  Try this: `width, height = getInt()`.

Comment: If i print the values in getInt i get them back as the values, i just cant get them into the other functions.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can try changing your main() into this

```
def main():
  width, height = getInt()
  print('Results: {}, {}'.format(width, height))  
  print('The perimeter is {}' .format(calcPerimeter(width, height)))
  print('The area is {}' .format(calcArea(width, height)))
```

you need to return getInt() to specific variable, before passing into another function

the other ways is calling calculatePerimeter and calculateArea inside the getInt() function, here is the example

```
def getInt():
    while True:
        width = int(input("Enter width (1 - 60):"))
        if width > 1 and width < 60:
            break
        else:
            print("Please enter a valid input")
    while True:
        height = int(input("Enter width (1 - 20):"))
        if height > 1 and height < 20:
        break
        else:
            print("Please enter a valid input")
    return calcPerimeter(width, height), calcArea(width, height)


def calcPerimeter(width, height):
    perimeter = (2 * (width + height))
    return perimeter  

def calcArea(width, height):
    area = width * height
    return area


def main():
  perimeter, area = getInt()
  print('Perimeter is {}, area is {}'.format(perimeter, area))  


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use Global Keyword. another way is to return the required variables from the function and saving them in the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

You should read this post and in general study the rules of variable scopes. As a programmer this is essential knowledge.

[Short Description of the Scoping Rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules)

Answer (score 0):

Refer this (link)[http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html] to understand why changing your `main` function to Po's answer makes the code run correctly.

The variables defined inside the functions `calcPerimeter` and `calcArea` are not visible/accessible to the `main` function because of being in a different scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
#I think i have resolved your problem.In your case it was returning list/tuple .you have to convert it into simple variable
def getInt():
  while True:
     width = int(input("Enter width (1 - 60):"))
     if width > 1 and width < 60:
        break
     else:
        print("Please enter a valid input")
while True:
    height = int(input("Enter height (1 - 20):"))
    if height > 1 and height < 20:
        break
    else:
        print("Please enter a valid input")
return width,height


 def calcPerimeter(width, height):
   hw=width+height
   perimeter = 2*hw
   return perimeter  

def main():
  width,height= getInt()
  p=calcPerimeter(width, height)
  print('The perimeter is %s'%p)
  a=calcArea(width, height)
  print('The area is %s'%a)


main()
```